# Своя сложная функция на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин, функции

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как это называется?:

```
var val1 = 'первое значение',
    val2 = 'второе значение';
str.myFunc(val1, val2);
```

Где функции вызываются как указано выше, а не `myFunc(val1, val2)`
Что-то напоминающее написание плагинов для jQuery, я про это имею ввиду:

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(val1, val2)
{
    // параметры плагина
}
```

Но чтоб вызывалось не так, `$(el).myFunc('первый параметр', { '': ... });`
а вот так, `'какое-то значение'.myFunc(val1, val2);`

Comment: это называется переменное число параметров. Если обьявление - это один случай, если вызов - это случай 2

Comment: Примерно так, как работает функция: `indexOf`, `substr` и другие подобные функции

Comment: @VladimirGamalian nick_n_a думаю ТС говорит про Method Chaining..... шо по-русски есть "цепочка" ..... которая применяется к объекту

Comment: Или имеется ввиду добавить в переменную именованую ф-цию?

Comment: стоит привести **полный** пример, а не _какое-то значение_.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, скорее все-таки расширение прототипа

Comment: @Grundy возможно. я вопрос еле еле освоил с пятого раза вообще)) так что мог ошибиться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется [Расширение нативных объектов JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes#native-prototype-change) . Делать это крайне не рекомендуется - так как может вызвать конфликт в JS-библиотеках/фреймворках, что приведёт к долгому отлаживанию - почему их заявленный функционал не работает или глючит.

Comment: старайтесь указывать ссылки на конкретный источник, ссылки на поисковые системы не приветствуются

Comment: @Grundy ок - поменял ссылкой на хорошую статью.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете добавить новую функцию в прототип объекта того типа с которым Вы работаете.

Пример:

```js
String.prototype.console = function(){console.log(this);}
"str".console()
```

Но лучше (из-за за того что может быть нарушена стандартная логика)  создать объект своего типа и реализовать для него нужный функционал.